# Java type erasure: How is type safety ensured?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure, erasure

As per type erasure mechanism in Java generics, a method:

```
boolean add(E e);
```

..gets compiled to

```
boolean add(Object e);
```

But then how is type safety ensured? As add now takes Object, I can pass String, Integer, Employee etc as all are sub-types of Object.

Comment: At the compilation stage, type information is intact, and so you cannot pass the non-E types into the method. Type safety only exists at the compilation stage. Period.

Comment: Don’t forget you can always just cast a generic type to a raw type and shove whatever you want in.

Comment: "gets compiled to" no, generic types in method signatures are preserved. That's how your compiler knows e.g. that `List.add(E)` requires an `E`, not an `Object`, even when you don't have the source code. (Try decompiling a generic class with `javap` to see this).